# Does there exist a singular function which is not monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a singular function which is not monotone?

I know about the Cantor-Lebesgue function $\varphi$ as the standard example of a singular function. If I take $f(x) = x-\varphi(x)$ then $f$ is not monotone, but it also stops being singular.

Comment: Take the Cantor-Lebesgue function on $[0,1]$ and its reflection about the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is the  Cantor function then $\sin ( \pi F(x))$ is singular and not monotone.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I'm missing something but I think we would need a shift like $\sin(1+F(x))$. Otherwise since $\sin$ is monotone in $[0,1]$ then $\sin(F(x))$ would still be monotone.

Comment: @Tiberio You are right. I have changed it to $\sin (\pi F(x))$.